# Rails 6 registraion modal with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm new to rails and I am trying to set modal for user login/registration.  I am able to get the modal to work but I canot figure out how to get the devise registraion to work in the modal.  I even tried createing a separate users/_new.html.erb file with my own registration form but when I try to submit from the modal I get an error no route matches post/.  I tried change the devise/registration/new.html.erb form to _new.html.erb but when I try to load the page I get an error:

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `resource' for
#<#Class:0x000000000ebf9b50:0x000000000ec0de70>
Did you mean?  rescue):

The above error happens when I render the standard devise/registrations/new.html.erb form.  I converted it to a partial and move it to the shared folder.

```
<h1><%= t('.sign_up') %></h1>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: 'email', class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: 'current-password', class: 'form-control' %>

    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
      <small class="form-text text-muted"><%= t('devise.shared.minimum_password_length', count: @minimum_password_length) %></small>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: 'current-password', class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.submit t('.sign_up'), class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render 'devise/shared/links' %>
```

The other way I tried it was posted the entire form in the modal on the nav page, but when I click submit, it goes to localhost.3000 and I get an error that no routes match post "/".
That form is, sorry, it's long, I have two forms in the modal:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="login" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="login" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg border-0">
    <div class="modal-content border-0">
      <div class="modal-content-head">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="login">Member Login</h5>  
        <button type="button" class="close text-right" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-5">
            <div class="row border-0">
              <div class="col-12 modal-content-subhead">
                Login
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-12 modal-content">
                <%= form_with(model: @user, class: "shadow p-3 mb-3 rounded text-light", local: true)  do |f| %>
                  
                  <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-12 col-form-label p-2">
                      <%= image_tag("layout/login/icon_reg_email.gif") %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-11 col-sm-12">
                      <%= f.email_field :email, class: "form-control shadow rounded", placeholder: "Email" %>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-12 col-form-label p-2">
                      <%= image_tag("layout/login/icon_reg_locked.gif") %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-11 col-sm-12">
                      <%= f.password_field :password, class: "form-control shadow rounded", placeholder: "Enter your password" %>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-12">
                      <%= f.submit "Log in", class: "btn btn-outline-light btn-lg" %>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                <% end %>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-1 text-center">
            <%= image_tag("layout/login/login_divider.gif") %>
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-5">
            <div class="row border-0">
              <div class="col-12 modal-content-subhead">
                Join
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-12 modal-content">
                <%= form_with(model: @user, class: "shadow p-3 mb-3 rounded text-light", local: true)  do |f| %>
                  
                  <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-12 col-form-label p-2">
                      <%= image_tag("layout/login/icon_reg_name_37_33.gif") %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-11 col-sm-12">
                      <%= f.text_field :first_name, class: "form-control shadow rounded", placeholder: "First Name" %>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-12 col-form-label p-2">
                      <%= image_tag("layout/login/icon_reg_name_37_33.gif") %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-11 col-sm-12">
                      <%= f.text_field :last_name, class: "form-control shadow rounded", placeholder: "Last Name" %>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-12 col-form-label p-2">
                      <%= image_tag("layout/login/icon_reg_email.gif") %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-11 col-sm-12">
                      <%= f.email_field :email, class: "form-control shadow rounded", placeholder: "Email" %>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-12 col-form-label p-2">
                      <%= image_tag("layout/login/icon_reg_locked.gif") %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-11 col-sm-12">
                      <%= f.password_field :password, class: "form-control shadow rounded", placeholder: "Enter your password" %>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-12">
                      <%= f.submit "Log in", class: "btn btn-outline-light btn-lg" %>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                <% end %>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-11 text-center">
            <%=link_to( image_tag("layout/facebook_login_200_42.gif"), user_facebook_omniauth_authorize_path) %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
---

Here is my routes.rb
~~~code
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, controllers: {omniauth_callbacks: 'omniauth'}
  root 'pages#index'
  get 'about', to: 'pages#about'
  resources :users, param: :username
  resources :clubs, param: :club_username
end
```

I'm happy to create my own or use the devise with some modifications but I just can't figure out how to do either.

Any help would be gretly appreciated.

Thanks,

Scott

Comment: Possible to share the line of code where this error is coming at, or a longer stack trace?

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the code for the view that is creating the error, it would also help you posted the whole error line rails gives you in there.  You should just be able to do something like `<%= render 'path/to/view' %>` in there but we need to see the code and error to debug it.

Comment: I editing and included my code. Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some more searching and was able to get it to work.  I uninstalled devise and tried it but couldn't get it to work so I reinstalled devise and omniauth and find an explanation to incorporating the devise forms into my app.

I installed the devise bootstrap views then in the layouts folder I created a partial named _login_html.erb and copied the login form and the sign upforms side-by-side:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="login" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="login" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg border-0">
    <div class="modal-content border-0">
      <div class="modal-content-head">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="login">Member Login</h5>  
        <button type="button" class="close text-right" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
            <div class="row border-0">
              <div class="col-12 modal-content-subhead">
                Login
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col modal-content">
                <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name), :remote => true) do |f| %>
                  
                  <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-form-label p-2">
                      <%= image_tag("layout/login/icon_reg_email.gif") %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-12">
                      <%= f.email_field :email, class: "form-control shadow rounded", placeholder: "Email", :autofocus => true, class: "form-control shadow rounded", placeholder: "Email" %>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-form-label p-2">
                      <%= image_tag("layout/login/icon_reg_locked.gif") %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-12">
                      <%= f.password_field :password, class: "form-control shadow rounded", placeholder: "Password" %>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
                    <div>
                      <%= f.check_box :remember_me %> <%= f.label :remember_me, class: "form_small_text" %>
                    </div>
                  <% end -%>
                  <div class="form-group row text-center">
                    <div class="col-12">
                      <%= f.submit "Sign in", :class => 'btn reg-submit-btn' %>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <%- if devise_mapping.recoverable? && controller_name != 'passwords' && controller_name != 'registrations' %>
                      <%= link_to t(".forgot_your_password"), new_password_path(resource_name), class: "form_small_text" %><br />
                    <% end -%>
                  </div>
                <% end %>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-1 text-center p-0">
            <%= image_tag("layout/login/login_divider.gif") %>
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7">
            <div class="row border-0">
              <div class="col-12 modal-content-subhead">
                Sign-Up
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col modal-content">
                <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), id: "form", :remote => true) do |f| %>
                  <%= devise_error_messages! %>
                  
                  <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-form-label p-2">
                      <%= image_tag("layout/login/icon_reg_name_37_33.gif") %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-12">
                      <%= f.text_field :first_name, class: "form-control shadow rounded", placeholder: "First Name" %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-12">
                      <%= f.text_field :last_name, class: "form-control shadow rounded", placeholder: "Last Name" %>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-form-label p-2">
                      <%= image_tag("layout/login/icon_reg_email.gif") %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-12">
                      <%= f.email_field :email, class: "form-control shadow rounded", placeholder: "Email", :autofocus => true %>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-form-label p-2">
                      <div class="reg_tooltip" data-tooltip="
                        The club username will be used to easily share your club page on this website.  
                        For example if your club username is my_club the url for your club page on this 
                        site will be www.themathouse.com/clubs/my_club.
                        ">
                        <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-question-diamond" fill="white" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                          <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M6.95.435c.58-.58 1.52-.58 2.1 0l6.515 6.516c.58.58.58 1.519 0 2.098L9.05 15.565c-.58.58-1.519.58-2.098 0L.435 9.05a1.482 1.482 0 0 1 0-2.098L6.95.435zm1.4.7a.495.495 0 0 0-.7 0L1.134 7.65a.495.495 0 0 0 0 .7l6.516 6.516a.495.495 0 0 0 .7 0l6.516-6.516a.495.495 0 0 0 0-.7L8.35 1.134z"/>
                          <path d="M5.255 5.786a.237.237 0 0 0 .241.247h.825c.138 0 .248-.113.266-.25.09-.656.54-1.134 1.342-1.134.686 0 1.314.343 1.314 1.168 0 .635-.374.927-.965 1.371-.673.489-1.206 1.06-1.168 1.987l.003.217a.25.25 0 0 0 .25.246h.811a.25.25 0 0 0 .25-.25v-.105c0-.718.273-.927 1.01-1.486.609-.463 1.244-.977 1.244-2.056 0-1.511-1.276-2.241-2.673-2.241-1.267 0-2.655.59-2.75 2.286zm1.557 5.763c0 .533.425.927 1.01.927.609 0 1.028-.394 1.028-.927 0-.552-.42-.94-1.029-.94-.584 0-1.009.388-1.009.94z"/>
                        </svg>
                      </div>
                      <%= image_tag("layout/login/icon_reg_name_37_33.gif") %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check col-md-10 col-sm-12">
                      <%= f.text_field :username, class: "form-control shadow rounded", placeholder: "Username", id: "username" %>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-form-label p-2">
                      <%= image_tag("layout/login/icon_reg_locked.gif") %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-12">
                      <%= f.password_field :password, class: "form-control shadow rounded", placeholder: "Password" %>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                    
                  <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-form-label p-2">
                      <%= image_tag("layout/login/icon_reg_locked.gif") %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-12">
                      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: "form-control shadow rounded", placeholder: "Confirm Password" %>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group row text-center">
                    <div class="col-12">
                      <%= f.submit "Sign up", :class => 'btn reg-submit-btn' %></div></p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                <% end %>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To make it work I added the following code to the helpers_application.

```
def resource_name
    :user
  end
    
  def resource
    @resource ||= User.new
  end
    
  def devise_mapping
    @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
  end
```

I think that's it.